# Get a list of google fonts in json format divided into unicode ranges

Tags: unicode, google-font-api, google-fonts

I use https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api for getting a list of google fonts.

The format is like this

```
{
 "kind": "webfonts#webfontList",
 "items": [



[...]


{
   "kind": "webfonts#webfont",
   "family": "Anonymous Pro",
   "variants": [
    "regular",
    "italic",
    "700",
    "700italic"
   ],
   "subsets": [
    "greek",
    "greek-ext",
    "cyrillic-ext",
    "latin-ext",
    "latin",
    "cyrillic"
   ],
   "version": "v3",
   "lastModified": "2012-07-25",
   "files": {
    "regular": "http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/anonymouspro/v3/Zhfjj_gat3waL4JSju74E-V_5zh5b-_HiooIRUBwn1A.ttf",
    "italic": "http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/anonymouspro/v3/q0u6LFHwttnT_69euiDbWKwIsuKDCXG0NQm7BvAgx-c.ttf",
    "700": "http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/anonymouspro/v3/WDf5lZYgdmmKhO8E1AQud--Cz_5MeePnXDAcLNWyBME.ttf",
    "700italic": "http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/anonymouspro/v3/_fVr_XGln-cetWSUc-JpfA1LL9bfs7wyIp6F8OC9RxA.ttf"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "webfonts#webfont",
   "family": "Antic",
```

In the github repository
https://github.com/asadkn
I found a list with google fonts divided into unicode ranges:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/asadkn/selfhost-google-fonts/master/inc/data/google-fonts-src.json

Does google offer this format, too? Is there another way to download the data in this format?